# How do I make validation text appear inside of a textbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, textbox

I am working in an asp.net mvc project and I would like my validation to appear inside of the textbox that it is pertinent to. Currently my code looks like this:

```
<div class="subStandardOption">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PdsToCreate.Standards.AudioFrequency)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PdsToCreate.Standards.AudioFrequency)
</div>
```

The validation **only** appears the user clicks the checkbox to the left of the text field then tries to submit the form and leaves the textbox is empty, so overwriting the current value is not a concern. When the checkbox is not checked, the textbox is disabled and no validation is necessary.

Comment: You mean you want to put a validation message inside a textbox, overwriting the value that the user has put there??

Comment: @RoyDictus I just clarified the question, the validation only appears when the box is empty.

Comment: So basically you want a watermark text in the textbox to say that it must be filled in?

Comment: @RoyDictus not exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HTML5 placeholder to show the required format:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PdsToCreate.Standards.AudioFrequency, new { placeholder = "e.g. 20 Hz" })
```